# mysql - search for ID with Partitions defined takes long time

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of log records. I read about `MySql-Partitions` and decided to create partitions of date-range. This was very useful when I needed to search for a log, as long as I knew the dates that the log could be in. but when I need to search for a list of logs (each could be on a different date) it takes lots of time to receive, I'm using the `find_in_set()` to get the list of logs.

when I didn't use the partitions the search for list took much much less, I understand why it's happening, my question is -> **Is there a better query to get the list of logs while still using the partitions?**

Thanks in advance.

code example:

```
SELECT log.*
FROM dbo.logs_1 as log
WHERE find_in_set(log.LogId, '43859,43860,43861,43862,43863,43864,43872,43876,43910,43911,43913,43918,43919,43922,43923,43924,43926,43927,43928')
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can do away with that call to `FIND_IN_SET`, and instead use `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT log.*
FROM dbo.logs_1 as log
WHERE log.LogId IN (43859,43860,43861,43862,43863,43864,43872,43876,43910,43911,43913,43918,43919,43922,43923,43924,43926,43927,43928);
```

MySQL should create a hash of the values in the `WHERE IN` clause, to speed up searching against those values.  Beyond this, for possibly faster performance, you could create another table containing these values, index the column, and then join to the `logs_1` table.

```
SELECT log.*
FROM dbo.logs_1 AS log
INNER JOIN log_ids li
    ON log.LogId = li.LogId;
```

Comment: sorry, new to MySql. how index the column will speed up the search? may you provide me a link to an example, please?

Comment: Use inner join instead of IN operator.